# If graph is tree what can be said about its adjacency matrix ? 

Tags: graph-theory, it.information-theory, coding-theory

**Question** If graph is tree what can be said about its [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) ?  And vice versa ?

Especially I am interested in case  when graph is [bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph).

Such graphs are related to error-correction codes (see e.g. [Adjacency matrices of graphs as parity check matrices of error correcting codes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89658/adjacency-matrices-of-graphs-as-parity-check-matrices-of-error-correcting-codes) ). 
If they are trees [belief propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belief_propagation) is known to produce exact results.

Comment: Every tree is a bipartite graph and the adjacency matrix is therefore of this form http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Adjacency_matrix_of_a_bipartite_graph 



Comment: If a graph is a tree then its adjacency matrix can be written in the form $N + N^T$ where $N$ is nilpotent (pick a root and direct all the edges towards it). 

Comment: The Smith Normal Form of the adjacency matrix must be $(1,\dots,1,0)$.

Comment: All trees are bipartite. As the comments show many strange things can said about their adjacency matrices. Voting to close.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: If an undirected graph with no loops is not a tree, you can still write its adjacency matrix as $N + N^T$ where $N$ is nilpotent. Is there something related to this which is particular to trees?

Comment: Despite the votes to close, I think this is a reasonable question, just the accents should be changed; say, like this: what is the (most) efficient way to tell from the adjacency matrix whether the graph is a tree?

Comment: I am sorry if the question is stupid or whatever, I am not an expert in graphs or coding (which is motivation). Just sometimes learning something about coding, so questions arises, and "ask stupid questions on MO" I think good way to learn. Any way the comments and answers are very interesting and helpful for me !  Let me explain motivation: codes are often given by parity check matrix which is "N"-matrix (adjance = N+N^t) for corresponding bipartitre graph. So looking on such matrix I want to understand is it tree ? "how far" it from tree? The reason is that Belief Prop. works well for trees

Comment: Trees are connected graphs with one more vertex than edge. It's easy and fast to check whether you have a tree by using, for example, breadth first search, a standard graph algorithm. One distance from a tree is the excess in the edges over the number of edges in a tree. If this isn't satisfactory, please explain why not. I don't see how any of this is research level.

Comment: @Douglas: I think the question of what are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the adjacency matrix of a bipartite graph seems quite interesting.  And thinking about it below (with your much appreciated assistance) led me to observe some things I hadn't known before about symmetric functions -- that you can take any of the usual bases for symmetric functions (power sum, elementary, Schur, etc.), look at the algebra generated by only the generators of even degree (e.g. kill the odd degree power sums as below) and get the ring of symmetric functions in the new variables $x_1^2, x_2^2, \dots $.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A graph is bipartite iff the odd powers of the adjacency matrix have all 0's on the diagonal.  So this implies that the sum of the $i$-th powers of the eigenvalues is 0 for each odd $i$.  Since the adjacency matrix is symmetric, it has real eigenvalues.  Thus, the eigenvalues are real numbers $\lambda_1,\dots ,\lambda_n $ with $\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j^i = 0$ for each odd $i$.

I am guessing this probably should mean that the nonzero eigenvalues come in pairs of equal magnitude and opposite sign.  I wonder if there is a good trick for efficiently proving this sort of thing -- about collections of real numbers satisfying such an infinite family of relations?  (If so, I don't know this trick.)

${\bf Edit:}$ Douglas Zare proved my above conjecture as a comment, so it is true for bipartite graphs that the nonzero eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix come in pairs of equal magnitude and opposite sign.

Comment: You can modify any eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ by negating the values on one of the parts to get an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-\lambda$.

Comment: I see -- you have given a proof of my conjecture in the specific case of adjacency matrices of bipartite graphs (rather than working with the relations among real numbers), noting that the standard basis vectors are indexed by the nodes of the graph and that applying the adjacency matrix sends a node to the sum of standard basis vectors indexing its neighbors.  That's a nice proof!  Thanks!

Comment: Now I'm also curious about the general statement for real numbers $\lambda_1, \dots ,\lambda_n$ of whether knowing $\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j^i =0$ for all positive, odd integers $i$ implies that the nonzero reals come in pairs $\mu_j, \nu_j$ of equal magnitude and opposite sign.  It looks like this might follow from a variant on the Vandermonde determinant being nonzero where the usual Vandermonde matrix entry $a_i^j$ is replaced by $\mu_i^j + \mu_i^{j-1}\nu_i + \mu_i^{j-2}\nu_i^2 + \cdots + \nu_i^j$.

Comment: @tweetie-bird: Look at the characteristic polynomial $P(x)=\prod(x-\lambda_i)$. Since your odd-power sums vanish then $\log P(x)$ is even. This implies $P$ is even so the roots come in pairs $\pm \lambda$.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm a little slow in understanding your comment though I'm afraid.  I don't yet see how to deduce that $log P(x)$ is even.  I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: I had a typo, I meant $\prod (1-x\lambda_i)$.

Comment: Actually, you can show that the elementary symmetric functions $e_i$ for $i$ odd are all 0 by expressing them in terms of the power sum symmetric functions and seeing that each summand is 0.  Then shows that the coefficients for odd powers of $x$ in your original $P(x)$ are 0, implying $P(x)$ is an even function.  This is interesting to think about what happens when you take the symmetric functions and mod out by the elements of odd degree in a basis.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

check the "matrix tree theorem"

So, a tree has only one spanning tree (which is itself of course), and conversely, if a graph has only one spanning tree, it must be a tree. Hence using the matrix tree theorem, which as you say counts the number of spanning trees, we can determine if a general graph is a tree or not.

Comment: What is the connection? The matrix-tree theorem counts spanning trees in a general graph. The OP asked something about trees (or bipartite graphs).

Comment: So, a tree has only one spanning tree (which is itself of course), and conversely, if a graph has only one spanning tree, it must be a tree. 

Hence using the matrix tree theorem, which as you say counts the number of spanning trees, we can determine if a general graph is a tree or not.

